# NSMutableArray as @property with readonly

Tags: objective-c

Suppose I have something like this:

```
@property (readonly) NSMutableArray *someArray;
```

Can I modify [obj someArray] even though the @property is set to readonly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can modify its contents. The readonly only applies to the pointer itself - in that way, it is *not* like C++'s `const`.

Basically, saying "readonly" just means "don't translate `a.someArray = foo` into `[a setSomeArray:foo]`". That is, no setter is created.

(Of course, if you wanted to prevent modification, you'd just use an `NSArray` instead.)

Comment: You mean C's "const". Quick point about C... it depends what side of the asterisk the "const" is on. The readonly property here IS like NSMutableArray * const someArray; but NOT like const NSMutableArray *someArray;

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness

Answer (score 3):

The contents of someArray are modifiable, although the property is not (i.e. a call cannot change the value of the `someArray` instance variable by assigning to the property). Note, this is different from the semantics of C++'s `const`. If you want the array to be actually read-only (i.e. unmodifiable by the reader), you need to wrap it with a custom accessor. In the `@interface` (assuming your `someArray` property)

```
@property (readonly) NSArray *readOnlyArray;
```

and in the `@implementation`

```
@dynamic readOnlyArray;

+ (NSSet*)keyPathsForValuesAffectingReadOnlyArray {
  return [NSSet setWithObject:@"someArray"];
}
- (NSArray*)readOnlyArray {
  return [[[self someArray] copy] autorelease];
}
```

Note that the caller will still be able to mutate the state of objects in the array. If you want to prevent *that*, you need to make them immutable on insertion or perform a depp-copy of the array in the `readOnlyArray` accessor.

Comment: "Note, this is different from the semantics of C++'s const." depends on where the "const" is placed

Comment: Could you explain why you use @dynamics verses not writing it?

Comment: @docchang Just to be explicit. the `@dynamic` is not necessary, but is a nice reminder to future readers that you *intend* to provide the implementation rather than synthesizing it.